# "Expected resource of type interpolator [ResourceType]" and "Cannot resolve symbol" error when generate a signed APK

Tags: android, android-studio

I have tested my app on many devices and everything goes well but when I'm trying to generate a signed apk this message appears: **Expected resource of type interpolator [ResourceType]**

This line seems the problem:

```
scaleDown.setInterpolator(AnimationUtils.loadInterpolator(activity, android.R.anim.decelerate_interpolator));
```

Behind this line there is a class called AnimationUtils, this class belongs to android SDK so I don't understand why when I inspect its the source code the following imports show me `Cannot resolve symbol`

```
import android.annotation.AnimRes;
import android.annotation.InterpolatorRes;
```

I already tried clean and rebuild.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally overcome this issue replacing

```
AnimationUtils.loadInterpolator(activity, android.R.anim.decelerate_interpolator)
```

To this

```
new DecelerateInterpolator()
```

Answer (score -1):

1.try to change android.R.anim.a to R.interpolater.b

Comment: What? I dont understand, i don't have `android.R.anim.a`

Comment: Thats only valid if you have the interpolator resource in your local files. As this is not the case when loading an interpolator from Android directly this proposal is nonsense.